# QImage data alignment

Tags: qt, alignment, qimage

The documentation of

`QImage::QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = Q_NULLPTR, void *cleanupInfo = Q_NULLPTR)`

describes that the data, refered by parameter 'data', must be 32 bit aligned. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-3 But it's at least unclear what is meant exactly. I assume, each pixel takes 32 bits. But that is not the case. Constructing an image like this is working:

```
uint8_t* rgb = new uint8_t[3 * height * width];
QImage Img(rgb, width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

But this is confusing. When I want to get the pixel values from the image, I thought I need to do this (since the data is 32 bit aligned and Qrgb is 32 bit):

```
QRgb*rawPixelData = (QRgb*) Img.bits();
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < (Img.width * Img.height); ++i)
{
  qDebug() << "Red" << qRed(rawPixelData[i]);
  qDebug() << "Green" << qGreen(rawPixelData[i]);
  qDebug() << "Blue" << qBlue(rawPixelData[i]);
}
```

But this is not working (leads to a crash). So, I assume, the data is not 32bit aligned. So, isn't the data 32 bit aligned, or I'm understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by the "data" they mean the array of bytes used. And by alignment they mean that the first byte of the array would be 32bit aligned and thus `data % 4` would always be 0. It is not the internal alignment of every pixel, just the alignment of the memory block that contains the pixel data.

Furthermore, `bits()` returns a pointer to an unsigned byte, not a pointer to a `QRgb`. A `QRgb` is essentially just an integer:

```
typedef unsigned int QRgb;
```

I suspect you are getting a crash because the raw data is "compacted". Meaning that if your image has only RGB and no alpha, it will use only 24bits or 3 bytes per pixel, because that would eliminate a 25% memory usage overhead. As a result, you are walking off the actual data and getting a crash.

You should try iterating it as `w * h * 3` unsigned chars and incrementing by 3 for each next pixel, and your rgb would be respectively the bytes at `i, i+1, i+2`.

It could probably work if your image format was RGBA.

And indeed if you bother to check the `byteCount` you'd realize that the amount of bytes used internally are the minimum amount for a given format:

```
  QImage img(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB888);
  qDebug() << img.byteCount(); // 30000 or 3 bytes or 24 bits

  QImage img2(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGB555);
  qDebug() << img2.byteCount(); // 20000 or 2 bytes or 15 bits

  QImage img3(100, 100, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
  qDebug() << img3.byteCount(); // 40000 or 4 bytes or 32 bits
```

Answer (score 2):

> But it's at least unclear what is meant exactly.

The expression is part of the software engineering vernacular and has nothing to do with the specific situation at hand: it doesn't have anything to do with Qt nor images nor pixels.

On *platforms where Qt is supported*, it has the following strict meaning:

```
uchar *data = ...;
Q_ASSERT(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data) & 3 == 0);
```

Or, on an arbitrary C++17 platform, it has the following strict meaning:

```
size_t size = ...;
uchar *data = ...;
Q_ASSERT(std::align(4, size, reinterpret_cast<void*&>(data), size) ==
         reinterpret_cast<void*>(data));
```